# Nested self join, how can I fix it?

Tags: sql

SQL can't cast those 2 tables together, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
select * from 
(select ID from tbl_Message
WHERE ([From_User] = '38137F2C-591C-4BE6-91F8-F2C915F26066' OR [To_User] = '38137F2C-591C-4BE6-91F8-F2C915F26066') 
AND [Replied_ID] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
and deleted = 0 ) tbl1 inner join
(select top 1.Replied_ID as Reply_ID, Post_Date as Reply_Date from tbl_Message 
where Replied_ID = tbl1.ID or ID = tbl1.ID
order by Post_Date desc) tbl2 on tbl2.Reply_ID =tbl1.ID
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific DBMS, since there are differences in syntax and capabilities between MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Post your Error Message.

Comment: its `sql-server` i guess !!

Comment: And explain a little what you are trying to do in the query. It is a little confusing what you might want to do

Comment: Question seems simple if any of you just saw at query structure I have already posted answer. He is new to this forum may be that's why he just explain it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are unable to run query as structure is not correct I have updated your query try it.

```
select * from (
(select ID from tbl_Message
WHERE ([From_User] = '38137F2C-591C-4BE6-91F8-F2C915F26066' OR 
[To_User] = '38137F2C- 591C-       4BE6-91F8-F2C915F26066') 
AND [Replied_ID] = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
and deleted = 0 ) tbl1
inner join
(select top 1.Replied_ID as Reply_ID, Post_Date as Reply_Date from tbl_Message 
where Replied_ID = tbl1.ID or ID = tbl1.ID
order by Post_Date desc) tbl2 
on tbl2.Reply_ID =tbl1.ID ) as temp
```

if everything else you are doing is right it must work.